# Using Google fonts: however, the code is not valid HTML5 according to W3C?

Tags: html, validation, fonts

I'm working on an assignment, and I am using Google Fonts for my site. I'm trying to validate my HTML using W3C, as my assignments must be valid to get full marks, and I keep on getting an error for the Google Font code. I can't seem to figure out why. Here's the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron|Special+Elite|Open+Sans">
```

Here's the error message I am getting from W3C:

> Bad value http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron|Special+Elite|Open+Sans for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.
>
> …href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron|Special+Elite|Open+Sans">
>
> Syntax of IRI reference:
>       Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

Any thoughts? I'm pretty new to HTML5, so I'm unsure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 11):

The offending character here is “|” U+007C VERTICAL LINE, used by Google as a separator between font names; that’s a poor choice by them, since “|” is a reserved character, both by the [“URL Living Standard”](http://url.spec.whatwg.org) (which is what the HTML5 CR cites) and by the Internet-standard STD 66 ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)).

In practice, it works fine when you use “|” as such, but to conform to the standards and drafts, use percent encoding (% encoding, as defined in the URL specifications) for it, writing `%7c` (case insensitive) instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron%7cSpecial+Elite%7cOpen+Sans">
```

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the pipe | with %7c and see if it will pass and still load the font on the webpage. You may have to do the same thing for the plus sign.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp