# W3C Validation Error in Linking Google Fonts Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

Google Fonts Link:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300italic,400italic,400,300,600,700,900|Varela|Arapey:400,400italic' rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```

W3C Validation Error:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300italic,400italic,400,300,600,700,900|Varela|Arapey:400,400italic for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.

[image]

I couldn't find any error in `link`. Please help me validate my CSS.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466913/google-fonts-url-break-html5-validation-on-w3-org or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926986/using-google-fonts-however-the-code-is-not-valid-html5-according-to-w3c

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Thanks :)